# How to calculate image rotation from touches?

Tags: iphone, geometry, rotation

I'm an iphone developer, but this question is about geometry.

I have a simple rectangle (maybe a photo). The user touches this photo at a point and drags their finger to a new point:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/792862/Untitleddrawing.png

How many radians I must rotate this rectangle to simulate a rotation given by the touches?

Comment: Where's the center of rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a fixed origin for your rotation (the crosshair in your picture would suggest so) and the touch sets the other point.

First you need a method to figure out the angle of a line. The [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function (available in any well-equipped math library) figures out the angle between any line and the X axis. First figure out the starting angle:

```
startAngle = atan2(startY - originY, startX - originX)
```

And then the ending angle:

```
endAngle = atan2(endY - originY, endX - originX)
```

And then just subtract the two angles from each other to figure out your rotation:

```
angleToRotate = endAngle - startAngle
```

You might need to swap things around depending on which way your rotations work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`atan2`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atan2.3.html) to convert the starting point and the ending point to angles, after translating each to correct for a non-(0,0) origin if necessary.